# Java : decrypt the string using RSA Private Key ( Xml signature )

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I have to decrypt the string which is encrypted using RSA xml signature public key in .NET 
I tried with php RSA Crypt Module which throws error.So, I want to do using Java . I am  little new java. Sample code would be much helpful.

Actually I need to port this  following .Net code to Java

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize);
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(privateKey);
int base64BlockSize = ((keySize / 8) % 3 != 0) ? (((keySize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((keySize / 8) / 3) * 4;
int iterations = inputString.Length / base64BlockSize;
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{                                                                               
   byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));
   Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
   arrayList.AddRange(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false));
}                                                                                                   lstrResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arrayList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.Byte")) as byte[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the .Net XML key representation and store the exponent and modulus in a Java [RSAPrivateKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateKeySpec.html). Pass this instance to the `generatePrivate` method of a [KeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) to generate a key.

You then need a [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) instance obtained by the `Cipher.getInstance` method with the alogorithm that fits the .Net implementation. The cipher needs to be initialized properly also. Using the gained `RSAPrivateKey` instance (see above) you then may call one of the ciphers method to decrypt the data.

The Devil is in the details, of course: decoding and formatting of the key material, finding the right algorithm, initialisation...

Comment: Do you mean `Cipher.getInstance()`?